# Spinner Fragment continually crashes

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am making a program that will include a Spinner within a fragment rather than an activity. I have researched why this may be crashing, but to no avail. My initial concern was a .getView().findViewById(), but now I'm not so sure that's the problem because . Here's the code.

```
public class Add extends Fragment {


public Add() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
SpinnerDialog spinnerDialog;
Button add;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    add = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();

        }

    });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    spinnerDialog = new SpinnerDialog(getActivity(), ingredients, "Select An Ingredient");
    spinnerDialog.bindOnSpinerListener(new OnSpinerItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String Ingredient, int i) {

            Toast.makeText(Add.super.getContext(), "Selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the stack trace I cannot say for sure, but I suspect this line is crashing:

```
add = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.add);
```

This is because `getView()` will return the `View` instance returned by `onCreateView()`... but you're currently *inside* `onCreateView()`, so `getView()` will return `null`.

You can re-write your `onCreateView()` as follows and it should work.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
    add = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```